# What is this series called? $\frac{x^1}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!} \dots \pm \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I remember learning about this series in Precalculus the other day but I neglected to get the name of it. It looks something like this:

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^1}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!} \dots \pm \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
$

All I remember is that it helps in the modeling of $\sin{x}$.

Comment: I believe you're misremembering the series. If you switch the numerator and denominator and let $n \to \infty$ you get the Taylor series expansion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\sin x$.

Comment: @qiaochu-yuan Yeah, I flipped them on accident. Thanks for the tip

Comment: since factorials grow very fast, as a practical matter one can actually use a "partial sum" of that series to obtain reasonably good estimates of $\sin(x)$, just 3 terms will give you 3 decimals places, and the first term alone makes it plausible that for $x$ close to $0$, $\sin(x)$ will be very close to $x$ (and why the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ is $1$ as $x$ approaches $0$, as you can see by dividing each term in the series by $x$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This
$$
\frac{x^1}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!} \dots \pm \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
Is called a Maclaurin polynomial for the sine function.

Comment: Thaaaat's the one! I remember that my teacher used a name that wasn't "Taylor" or anything like that. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure you didn't get the summands flipped?

The following series is called the [Taylor series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\sin{x}$:

\begin{align*}
\sin{x} &= x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} \\[8pt]
\end{align*}

It's [derived here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition).

Comment: This is also shown in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125543/).

Answer (score 6):

I think you're interested in the [Taylor expansion of $\sin x$](http://home.scarlet.be/math/taylor.htm#Expansion-of-sin(x)) <strike>but the fractions go other way round!</strike>

- [Wiki Books Link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Taylor_series)

**Related Reading on the Site:**

1. [Intuition explanation of taylor expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/intuition-explanation-of-taylor-expansion)
2. [Taylor series for different points... how do they look?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77643/taylor-series-for-different-points-how-do-they-look) (Cool Animations by JM)
3. [On what interval does a Taylor series approximate (or equal?) its function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12862/on-what-interval-does-a-taylor-series-approximate-or-equal-its-function)
4. Example to help compute Taylor Series of a function: [Basic Taylor expansion question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14887/basic-taylor-expansion-question)

Comment: @TheChaz It is `<strike>blah</strike>` And this mark up fails in comments: <strike>Test</strike> ---Test--- works on chat but not here.